# LDAP passwords encryption (userPassword attribute)

Tags: ldap, password, perl, md5

I'm trying to import passwords from an LDAP to a MySQL database. When I look at the `userPassword` attribute for the known password `test` I get this:

```
userPassword:: e01ENX1DWTlyelVZaDAzUEszazZESmllMDlnPT0=
```

The password at this stage is `base64` encoded, after decoding I get this:

```
{MD5}CY9rzUYh03PK3k6DJie09g==
```

-It doesn't look like the `CY9....` string is an MD5 hash because it isn't 32-character long (actually 128-bit).
-It doesn't seem to be `base64` encoded either as I don't get `test` after decoding.
-Also when I generate my own `MD5` hash out of `test` I get `098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6`.

I found [this perl script](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/418.html) (second one on the page) which does generate `{MD5}CY9rzUYh03PK3k6DJie09g==` from `test` but when I look at the script I don't see what I'm missing as it does look like the `md5` hash gets `base64` encoded before being concatenated with `{MD5}`:

```
$ctx = Digest::MD5->new;
$ctx->add('secret');
$hashedPasswd = '{MD5}' . encode_base64($ctx->digest,'');
```

**Can someone explain the step to get from `test` to `CY9rzUYh03PK3k6DJie09g==`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked the second parameter of the PHP md5() function?

```
cat md5.php 
<?php echo base64_encode(md5('test',true));

php md5.php 
CY9rzUYh03PK3k6DJie09g==
```

You should use the raw binary format (and that's why it was encoded with base64).